# "ReferenceError: require is not defined at Object.child_process" for Electron app while running karma test cases

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack, karma-jasmine

We have a Electron App build using Angular 4, NodeJS & Electron, Webpack.

We have few of the UI components calling child_process & fs modules, because of which we are getting below error while running test cases using karma:

> "HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR: 'ReferenceError:
>   require is not defined
>       at Object.child_process"

Please suggest ways to work around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to karma was trying to run test cases on Browser (Headlesschorme), which does not allow running chid_process.

So used karma-electron plugin to let karma run test cases on electron launcher.

Refeer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-electron